# Jenkins pipeline for golang tests which interact with mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins

My jenkins config looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        stage('Pre Test'){
            steps {
                sh 'go version'
                sh '...'
            }
        }
        stage('Test'){
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'mysql/mysql-server'
                    args '--name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= -d'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'export test_db_host="tcp(mysql:3306)" && go test'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when reaching the `'Test'` stage I get the error:

```
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/app-backend@2\") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory": unknown
process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/app-backend@2@tmp/durable-169602da
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I do not think you are supposed to have a `-d` in the `args` for a docker agent in jenkins pipeline and that would cause conflicts. I also do not think you can do an agent override in pipeline and have to establish `agent none` at the top level if you want to do per-stage agents. I could be wrong on either or both though.

Comment: I got the code from https://serverfault.com/questions/918765/set-up-database-for-integration-testing-with-jenkins-in-docker/918865 which came from https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-docker-with-pipeline :)

Comment: Actually the documentation you linked to supports both of my concerns.

Comment: How come @MattSchuchard? I am very confused by all this... All I want is to run golang tests which use mysql.

Comment: @MattSchuchard is absolutely right

Comment: did you define working dir on your dockerfile ?